# how can i install cassandra GUI in centos7

Tags: user-interface, cassandra

hay folks,
I want to install Cassandra gui in centos 7 currently I have only cli host but I will add this to gui , I am looking for a tutorial to install Cassandra GUI in centos 7

Comment: Netflix just open sourced theirs.  Give it a look: https://github.com/Netflix/nf-data-explorer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "Cassandra GUI".

There are tools that you could use to connect to Cassandra but none of them are part of the Cassandra binaries. Cheers!

Comment: ok make sense so how can i install these tool for cassandra

Comment: Which tool are you after?

Comment: well i dont know i am newbie in this i want to know which tool i have to install

Comment: Cassandra isn't like other traditional RDBMS. It sounds like you are completely new so I highly recommend doing the free browser-based tutorials we have here -- https://www.datastax.com/learn/cassandra-fundamentals. It will give you the basics and get you started with Cassandra. Cheers!